# Just trying my second app but am getting an error "Unfortunately your app has stopped"..error caused by android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener

Tags: onclicklistener

```
package com.example.medreminder;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;``

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   String MedecineName;
   int DailyDozage , NoOfPiecesBought;

   EditText medecinename;
   EditText dailydozage;
   EditText noofpiecesbought;

   Button submitbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);





  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      medecinename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.medecinename);
      dailydozage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dailydozage);
      noofpiecesbought = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noofpiecesbought);

      submitbutton = findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
      submitbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
      submitbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
             MedecineName = medecinename.getText().toString();
             DailyDozage =Integer.valueOf(dailydozage.getText().toString());
             NoOfPiecesBought = Integer.valueOf(noofpiecesbought.getText().toString());


            showToast(MedecineName);
            showToast(String.valueOf(DailyDozage));
            showToast(String.valueOf( NoOfPiecesBought));

        }
    });
}

private void showToast(String Text)
{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Text , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

__________________________________________LOGCAT__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

03-13 17:44:04.993 5251-5256/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
03-13 17:44:05.075 5251-5251/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.medreminder, PID: 5251
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.medreminder/com.example.medreminder.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.medreminder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: What is the question ? Can you provide at least the context ?

Comment: Actually my app crashes when I try to open it and shows "unfortunately the app has stopped working"..... The logcat shows error on line 36... Related to onclicklistener. ........I am a be beginner and unable to correct the mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call setOnClickListener on a null object reference. Your `submitbutton` is referring to null.

**You are doing it twice**-

```
submitbutton =findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
submitbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
```

**Do it once**
submitbutton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);